# Why is calling cursor.executemany() with fast_executemany=True resulting in a segmentation fault?

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pyodbc, freetds

I have a pydodbc cursor connected to an Azure SQL database with the latest version of FreeTDS installed running on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test(a INT, b INT)")
cursor.commit()
```

This works, fine, then I try

```
cursor.fast_executemany=True
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test(a, b) VALUES(?,?)", [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])
```

Which results in a segmentation fault, and the only error message I see is `segmentation fault: 11`

If I do not set `cursor.fast_executemany=True`, then the code works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your "segmentation fault" issue under Xubuntu 16.04 using FreeTDS 1.00.94 and unixODBC 2.3.6.

`fast_executemany = True` uses an ODBC feature called "parameter arrays" and that feature is not supported by all ODBC drivers. Apparenty FreeTDS ODBC is one of those drivers that does not support it.

If you really need to use `fast_executemany = True` you can use [Microsoft's ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server). It does support ODBC parameter arrays.